# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in add_product.php on line 29

Tags: php, mysql, dbo

Sorry very new to PHP and mySQL.

Here is the code there error is referring to.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO movies
            (title, year, actor, notes, category)
          VALUES
            (:code, :name, :price, :notes, :category_id)';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':title', $code);
$statement->bindValue(':year', $name);
$statement->bindValue(':actor', $price);
$statement->bindValue(':notes', $notes);
$statement->bindValue(':category', $category_id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

The error is refering to the execute(); statement
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this with proper variable binding, **you've used wrong names** while doing it. Let's do it-

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO
            movies(title, year, actor, notes, category)
          VALUES 
            (:code, :name, :price, :notes, :category_id)';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':code', $code); // see the changes here 
$statement->bindValue(':name', $name); // see the changes here 
$statement->bindValue(':price', $price); // see the changes here 
$statement->bindValue(':notes', $notes);// see the changes here  
$statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id); // see the changes here 
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

PDOStatement::bindValue — Binds a value to a parameter.

**parameter**

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named
>   placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.

**value**

> The value to bind to the parameter.

But in your case you used different names while using `bindValue()`. See more http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: I am working on a project from class and pulled this from a different project that had different titles. would the changes you made to ':code'. $code); still work with the above statement of insert into movies(title, year, actor, notes, category) or would I need to change them to code, name, price, etc as well?

Comment: @jriding mate I didn't got your point properly. Let me edit my answer and add more verbose explanation to make it more clearer to you.

Comment: again thank you for your time and explanation. I am thinking I may have to go thru all of the code and make sure everything matches to what the database columns are so I do not make mistakes from misspellings.

Comment: I believe I understand what the reference url was saying. I will go thru my code and clean it up and if I still have issue will re post. Thanks again for the information.